# Removing numbers using NSnumberformatter from a calculated number

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I have a calculation that calculate square meters from millimeters and for this to show corect I would like to remove all numbers after the 2 first digits.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
let spha = sizeh.wshight()
    let spwa = sizew.wswidth()
    let areas1 = areaModel(pwa:spwa, pha:spha)


    let formatter5 = NSNumberFormatter ()
        formatter5.maximum = 2
    let scarea = formatter5.stringFromNumber(areas1.sarea())!


    screenAreaLabel?.text = "\(scarea)sqm"
```

I am a little lost at this point, I am using Float in calculation of this area.

Hope someone could help me in the right direction.

More detail info added.

[image: Image of app]

I would like the Screen Area to only show 24sqm not 24772610sqm

Comment: @Rob See attached image hope this explains it more. Basicly I am trying to get the square meter from Screen Size witch is in millimeter.

Comment: well obviously you should just divide the result by `1_000_000` to convert it from square milimeters to square meters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are multiplicating a value in millimeter by another value in millimeters, therefore the result is in square millimeters.

To convert square millimeters to square meters, just divide the result by `1_000_000`.

You could also set `formatter.multiplier` to `1.0 / 1_000_000`.

Comment: Doh, sometimes I get caught up in trying to do things the hard way. But You are right :-) Thanks for that